# Can someone help me identify this pin?

Tags: identification

Recently I’ve got this pin as a present from my friend, but he didn’t know what this abbreviation (v.s.s?) means. I think it’s from German but I’m not sure.

[image]

Comment: Green and white are the colors of Saxony.

Comment: The squiggle in the "V" could actually be the one used in german [Kurrent](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift) or Süterlin script to mark an "u". (Although normally it is used to distinguish the small u from the identically-written n.) If that was the case, the pin could be an old version of the coat of arms used by [SuS Grün-Weiß Amecke 1922 e. V.](http://www.susgwamecke.de/), a sports club from Sundern/Sauerland (Northrine-Westphalia). The modern logo looks like it could fit. SuS is short for "Spiel-und Sportverein" (Games and Sports club).

Comment: @ccprog  This looks pretty likely to me!